# How do holo calls work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I just finished a group mission and when I went to turn in, two of the party members "dialed in" via holo calls.

How does that work?

Does someone need to go start the conversation and others can be anywhere on the map? Does my character need to own a particular item before being able to turn in a quest like this or are holo calls available to everyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a holocall to work, there needs to be someone to start the conversation, but then the others can participate from wherever they are -- I *think* they have to be out of combat at the time, and I believe there's code to stop you from being attacked while you're in a holocall -- but I haven't tested those.

It is worth noting that there are various dialogue options that you CAN'T do while on a holocall -- for instance, anything that involves handing the target something you obviously can't do while you're not there, so it will be grayed out. As a consequence of this, there will be some points in a holocall where you literally cannot do anything, and will need to wait out the timer in order for the conversation to proceed.

You still get the social points, though.

Answer (score 1):

The Holo call is exactly as you described it, someone in your party will start the conversation for the particular quest that if you have completed as well, you can join in via Holo Call if the person starting the conversation waits long enough for you too stand still and click the button for joining the conversation. It takes a second to load but works great if you arent ready to go turn in the quest and still wanna join in the conversation for the social points.